# Work with non-table values, aka "A is not subtractable"

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I see many similar questions but couldn't find a good match.
If we define a query and the result aught to be single value, is there a flux way to store as such? Example:

```py
total = from(bucket: "xxx")
  |> range(start: 0)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => ...)
  |> keep(columns: ["_value"])
  |> sum()

consumed = from(bucket: "xxx")
  |> range(start: 0)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => ...)
  |> keep(columns: ["_value"])
  |> last()

total - consumed
```

Results in

> invalid: error @18:1-18:40: [A] is not Subtractable

I can think of other ways to solve similar issues, but this example made me question whether flux actually supports easy working with single values or 1x1 relations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not answering my original question but I want to provide the workaround I went with to solve this. I would still be interested in a more direct solution.

I've introduced a second column, then joined the two tables on that column:

```cpp
total = from(bucket: "xxx")
  |> range(start: 0)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => ...)
  |> keep(columns: ["_value"])
  |> sum()
    // Added:
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ age: "latest", _value:r._value }))

consumed = from(bucket: "xxx")
  |> range(start: 0)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => ...)
  |> keep(columns: ["_value"])
  |> last()
    // Added:
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ age: "latest", _value:r._value }))

join(tables: {total: total, consumed: consumed}, on: ["age"])
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({_value: r._value_total - r._value_consumed}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the query, `total` and `consumed` are tables. For how to extract and use scalar values, please see [Extract scalar values in Flux](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/query-data/flux/scalar-values/)